# Where is my mistake in calculating $\int_{b}^{\infty} t\frac{ab^a}{t^{a+1}} \,dt = \frac{ab}{a-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I cant find my mistake could you take a look?

The integral and his solution is $\int_{b}^{\infty} t\frac{ab^a}{t^{a+1}} \,dt = \frac{ab}{a-1}$ for $a>1$.

Now my try:

$\begin{align}
\int_{b}^{\infty} t\frac{ab^a}{t^{a+1}} \,dt &= ab^a \int_{b}^{\infty} t\frac{1}{t^{a+1}} \,dt
= ab^a \int_{b}^{\infty} t\frac{1}{t^at} \,dt = ab^a \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^a} \,dt  \\
&= ab^a(\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{(a-1)t^{a-1}}} - \frac{1}{(a-1)b^{a-1}}) \\
&= ab^a(0-\frac{1}{(a-1)b^{a-1}})\\
&= -\frac{ab^a}{(a-1)b^{a-1}} \\
&= -\frac{ab^a}{(a-1)b^ab^{-1}} \\
&= -\frac{ab}{(a-1)}
\end{align}$

But it has to be wrong because there is a minus left, but I can not find my mistake.

BTW its the Pareto distribution.

Comment: You skip exactly the step where you made your mistake. Write down more detailed how you solved the integral

Comment: In short: $\int \frac{dt}{t^a} = \int t^{-a}\,dt = \frac{t^{-a+1}}{-a+1}+C$.

Comment: Instead of writing $ \frac{1}{u}$, write $u^{-1}$. That should resolve some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{t^a} dt= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{B}^R t^{-a} dt = \lim_{R \to \infty}  t^{-a+1}\frac{1}{-a+1}|_b^{R}  = \lim_{R \to \infty}  R^{-a+1}\frac{1}{-a+1}- b^{-a+1}\frac{1}{-a+1} $$

You got the opposite signs at this step.